# How to update a Databricks Delta table with inner join in Databricks using Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have to update a table column with inner join with other table.I have tried using the below sql.But i'm getting error in Databricks as (Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '' expecting 'WHEN').I tried different ways of updating the table.Can someone help me on this issue how to fix this?

```
%sql
merge into test a using test_1 b
on (a.id_num=b.id_num)
when matched then
update set a.name=b.name;
```

Comment: What are you trying to update? ORC table?

Comment: No it's a normal table.i want o update some columns of test table which those columns will  present in test_1 as well.In the above code i want to update a name column of test table.I have tried below query also.
update test t1 set name=(select t2.name from test_1 t2 where t1.id_num=t2.id_num ) where exists (select 1 from test_1 where t1.id_num=t2.id_num).It also gave me some error.

Comment: Is there another way to update apart from using Merge query like Update Table1 join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID ?

Answer (score 1):

Your table must be **DELTA** format. is it?

I think your command is ok.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/merge-into.html

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your question correct you want to use databricks merge into construct to update your table 1 (say destination) columns by joining it to other table 2( source)

```
MERGE INTO destination 
USING updates
ON destination.primary_key = source.foregin_key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET column1= updates.column1
```

Same query can be extended to insert data as well if no marching row is present in source and destination table.

- Note- My answer is based on assumption i made at the start. If you can elobrate further, that will be helpful for understanding your problem better

Answer (score 1):

```
%%sql
merge into test a using test_1 b
on (a.id_num=b.id_num)
when matched then
update set a.name=b.name;
```

use double % for this.

Comment: Plus 1 for actually including code...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Databricks Runtime Version, You need to use the `Databricks Runtime version 5.1` or above for your query on Delta Table. But for the merge operation, you need to have a Delta table first.

Answer (score 0):

query which you are using is correct. Reason for failure is you are not using delta tables, in your case test and test_1 should be delta tables.